# How does gettext figure out what languages are available

Tags: php, c, ubuntu, internationalization, gettext

I recently spent some time translating a PHP application, running on Linux with Apache2. To get gettext to work I needed to touch system directories for every language I wanted to support, so I wonder is there a easier way to support getting text from gettext in all languages.

My locales files are in a sub directory of my project:

```
./locale/sv_SE/LC_MESSAGES/default.po
./locale/es_BO/LC_MESSAGES/default.po
```

and the code: is in ./gettext.php like this:

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_BO.utf8");
bindtextdomain("default", "locale/"); # usually works
textdomain("default");
echo echo _("test");
?>
```

The C code is exactly the same code but with some headers.

This code will not output my Spanish translation if I do not "enable" Bolivian Spanish system wide with this ugly hack, linking the already existing sv_SE locale to es_BO:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/locale/sv_SE.utf8 /usr/lib/locale/es_BO.utf8
```

**Updates**

I think my question was wrong "So How do I avoid making that *ln -s* command, or just tell me if I'm going about this in the wrong way?" basically what I want to know if why gettext needs those files in /usr/lib/locale" or how I in a simple way are to use gettext to only translate messages.

**Update2** 
I tried using `setlocal(LC_MESSAGES, "es_BO.utf8")` but it still needs the messages in /usr/lib/locale.

Comment: One thing though I did try to use LC_MESSAGES instead of LC_ALL, thinking that perhaps. it needs to read date formatting and number formatting from gettext. That didn't help either I still need to have the language in /usr/lib/locale

Comment: Aha, your extra explanation makes a lot more sense now. I think Bort's got this one covered. :)

Comment: Yeah thanks for the pointer, I tend to get lost in my own (not so bright) literary brilliance. :-)

Comment: [PHP-I18N](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-I18N) works on all platforms and takes care of those tasks for you.

Answer (score 1):

For checking whether a certain translation works properly you should invoke the language environment properly as

```
#!/bin/bash
export LANG=es_BO
./yourprog
```

I think your current language hack works because LANG=sv_SE in your current system. Otherwise I recommend reading more about [gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html) .

Comment: Don't forget about `locale(7)`, it can be a nicer overview.

Comment: Interesting enough if I set locale with LANG=es_BO.utf8 it doesn't work, even with my hack.

Comment: I'm not sure what this answer means really, it might be anote to me that I'm not expressing my self clear enough. But basically I know that translation with gettext isn't working ok. I'm trying to understand why.

Answer (score 1):

Use `locale -a` to get a list of generated locales for your system.  To add to this list, edit `/etc/locale.gen` and rerun `locale-gen`.

(Also, gettext does not figure anything out at all, it tries to use the current locale, and if it fails, it can only fall back to `C`)